# How to restart a VM on GCP from another server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there any way to restart a VM on GCP from Internet using python, bash or php?

I need to restart when I get some notification.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use GCP's python client https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

Comment: Also read the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/reset) with examples in multiple languages.

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 things to do this:

- Being authenticated
- Use API to communicate with Compute Engine Google APIs (or client libraries that embed the API call)

**Authentication**

The easiest way is to use [gcloud sdk CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install). If you use your personal computer, you can use your personal user account, else, you can use a [service account with a service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys).

If you use a client library, you don't need to have gcloud sdk installed, only the service account key file is enough. One good practice is to define an environment variable [`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/serviceAccountKeyFile.json`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python).

*It's a good practice because you don't hardcode the way of authenticating your code. The library search by itself the credential in several location and you can run the same code seamlessly in your local environment and on GCP. No hack, do dirty code, no different entry point.*

**API Call**

If you use gcloud, you can reset your VM by using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/reset)

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -X POST \
  https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MyProjectId>/zones/<ComputeZone>/instances/<InstanceName>/reset
```

You can also use the [stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop) (wait 90s) and then re[start](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start) your VM. Same authentication, juste the URL are different. *It's important to wait at least the max stop grace period of 90s before triggering a start*

Sadly, there isn't Compute Engine client libraries. You can only use the discovery API. Not as handful as the other existing libraries. You have an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide). To reset, you have to call this [method in Python](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instances.html#reset)

```
  compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
  result = compute.instances().reset(project=<MyProjectId>, zone=<ComputeZone>, instance=<InstanceName>).execute()
```